# Is the linear functional that sums the coefficients of $p$ continuous on $P([a,b])$ with $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification

Is the linear functional that sums the coefficients of $p$ continuous on $P([a,b])$ with $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.

**My attempt:**

**Claim:** It is continuous.

When $1\in [a,b]$:

Since a linear functional is continuous if and only if its kernel is closed, it suffices to check that the kernel subspace 
$$\bigg\{ p \in P([a,b]) : p(x) = \sum a_n x^n \text{ with } \sum a_n = 0 \bigg\} = \big\{ p \in P([a,b]) : p(1) = 0 \big\}$$
is closed.

And the result is clear if $p_n \rightarrow p$ in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, then pointwise convergence holds which means 
$$p(1) = \lim_n p_n(1) = \lim_n 0 = 0$$
thus if $p_n$ is in the kernel, so is $p$, the kernel is closed.

For general case, can I expand the interval $[a,b]$ to $[a',b']$ such that both $[a,b]$ and $\{1\}$ are contained in $[a',b']$? Can we say $P([a,b])$ is a linear subspace of $P([a',b'])$ or is it only a subspace? If the linear functional is continuous on $P([a',b'])$, is it also continuous on $P([a,b])$?

Comment: What about $[a,b] = [0,1/2]$ and $p_n = x^n$? Is $\Vert p \Vert_\infty$ the sup-Norm of the function $x \mapsto p(x)$?

Comment: yes, we use the sup norm in the problem. For the sequence $p_n (x) = x^n$ in $P([0,1/2])$, they are not in the kernel, but they converge to the zero polynomial, which is in the kernel.

Comment: Yes, they are not in the kernel. But what is the exact value $\varphi(p_n)$, where $\varphi$ is your functional? What does this say about continuity of $\varphi$? You can also consider $p_n = 1 - x^n$.

Comment: ah, yes, thank you. $p_n = 1-x^n$ would be an example showing that $\phi$ is not continuous. Then is there a mistake in my argument? And this example can not be used for $[a,b]$ that contains $1$.

Comment: You argument is correct in the case $1 \in [a,b]$, because then (as you noted) $\phi(p) = p(1)$. My example above shows that **in general** for $1 \notin [a,b]$, the functional is **not** continuous (the example works on $[a,b]$ as long as $-1<a<b<1$). At the moment, I am not sure about the other cases (e.g. it could be that the claim is true if there is some $x \in [a,b]$ with $|x| \geq 1$). I will have to think about that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have shown, the functional (let me call it $\varphi$) is continuous (it coincides with $\phi(p) = p(1)$) as long as $1 \in [a,b]$.

The coincidence with $\phi(p) = p(1)$ also allows you to conclude that the functional is **not** continuous as soon as $1 \notin [a,b]$.

To see this, consider the compact(!) set

$$
K := \{1\} \cup [a,b].
$$

Then $f : K \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $f(1) = 1$ and $f|_{[a,b]} \equiv 0$ is continuous. By a theorem of (Stone)-Weierstraß, there is a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)_n$ with $p_n \to f$ uniformly on $K$ (if you know the theorem only on intervals, choose any compact interval $I \supset K$ and extend $f$ continously to $I$ (how?).)

But this implies $\phi(p_n) = p_n(1) \to f(1) = 1$ although

$$
\Vert p_n \Vert_{\infty, [a,b]} \to \Vert f \Vert_{\infty, [a,b]} = 0,
$$

because of uniform convergence.

The idea here was that the functional $\phi$ would provide a continous way of "evaluation of a function at $1$". I then used this intuition to provide a counterexample (because intuitively, the sup-norm on $[a,b]$ can not control $|f(1)|$, the argument above makes this rigorous.)